# Value of of SelectField in Python Flask is not being displayed correctly

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a python flask app im working on. One of my forms give the option to update lease details for existing leases. The form is accessed by a link to the lease which then queries the SQL DB for the lease details, and shows them in a pre-populated form. This works fine for all text fields, but when using a select field the value of the select field always goes to the first one, but if I inspect the source it shows its been passed the correct value from the SQL query.

[browser source page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jMpn.jpg)

The snippet from the html template is shown here

```
<p>
  {{ lease_update_form.lease_duration.label }}<br>
  {{ lease_update_form.lease_duration(class="form-control",value=lease_to_update.lease_duration) }}
</p>
```

**Routes**

```
@app.route('/leases/update/<int:lease_id>', methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_lease_update(lease_id):
    lease_update_form = Lease_Update_Form()
    lease_to_update = Leases_Model.query.get_or_404(lease_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        lease_to_update.lease_start_date = request.form['lease_start_date']
        lease_to_update.lease_duration = request.form['lease_duration']
        lease_to_update.rental_frequency = request.form['rental_frequency']
        lease_to_update.rental_amount = request.form['rental_amount']
        lease_to_update.lease_deposit_paid_amount = request.form['lease_deposit_paid_amount']
        lease_to_update.lease_deposit_paid_date = request.form['lease_deposit_paid_date']
        lease_to_update.lease_notes = request.form['lease_notes']
        lease_to_update.first_payment_date = request.form['first_payment_date']
        db.session.commit()
        return(render_template("lease_details.html", lease_update_form = lease_update_form, lease_to_update = lease_to_update))
```

Form snippet

```
class Lease_Update_Form(FlaskForm):
    tenant_id = QuerySelectField(query_factory=get_tenant, get_label='display_name')
    property_id = QuerySelectField(query_factory=get_property, get_label='display_name')
    lease_start_date = DateField(label='Lease Start Date')
    lease_duration_choices = ("1 week", "4 weeks", "3 months", "6 months", "12 months", "24 months", "36 months")
```

So in this example the SelectField should show 12 Months which is the value being pulled from the query, but instead if shows 1 week which is the first option available to select.

how can I get the select field to show the current value from the SQL query rather than the first choice available.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the field's [`data`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.data) attribute before rendering the form.

Suppose your `Leases_Model` stores the lease duration in a column called `lease_duration`, then you'd do something like:

```
@app.route('/leases/update/<int:lease_id>', methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_lease_update(lease_id):
    lease_update_form = Lease_Update_Form()
    
    lease_to_update = Leases_Model.query.get_or_404(lease_id)

    # Set the form field data e.g.
    # lease_update_form.lease_duration_choices.data = "12 Months"
    lease_update_form.lease_duration_choices.data = lease_to_update.lease_duration

    # ... more
```